# SQL - finding the minimal value of a specific group and giving extended information about it

Tags: sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group, partition-by

I would like to introduce myself as someone who has just recently started to fiddle a bit with SQL. Throughout my learning process I have come across a very specific problem and thus, my question is very specific too. Given the following table:

[image]

How should my list of commands look in order to get this following table:

[image]

In other words, what should I write to basically show the minimal salary and the id of its owner for each country. I have tried using GROUP BY but all I could get is the minimal salary per country whereas my goal was to show the id that belongs to the minimal salary too.

Hope I got my question clear and I thank everyone for the support.

Comment: Hello Solomon, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...? Also, please be aware that posting images is considered bad practice for SQL questions; data is better served as tabular text, or as `create table` and `insert` statements (so others can copy/paste it and play around with it).

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical greatest-n-per-group problem.

One cross-database solution is to filter with a subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.salary = (select min(t1.salary) from mytable t1 where t1.country = t.country)
```

For performance with this query, you want an index on `(country, salary)`.

You can also use window functions, if your database supports that:

```
select id, country, salary
from (
    select t.*, rank() over(partition by country order by salary) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do by

```
select
    id,
    country,
    salary
from
(
  select
    id,
    country,
    salary,
    row_number() over (partition by country order by salary) as rnk
  from table
)val
where rnk = 1
```